# Search through last 2 integers and compare in a map

Tags: scala, list

My system currently has the functionality to search through a mapped list of ints, each with key values, "sk1" - "sk10". I need to modify what I have now so that I can search through the list and compare the last 2 numbers in the list and return which is the highest.

Currently I can search for 1 and return the current, I need to search through all of the values and find the "Highest Increasing"

Below is my data file, "mapdata" I will give an example of what I need. This is stored as a Map[String, List[Int]]. String being the first value and the list of ints afterwards.

```
SK1, 9, 7, 2, 0, 7, 3, 7, 9, 1, 2, 8, 1, 9, 6, 5, 3, 2, 2, 7, 2, 8, 5, 4, 5, 1, 6, 5, 2, 4, 1
SK2, 0, 7, 6, 3, 3, 3, 1, 6, 9, 2, 9, 7, 8, 7, 3, 6, 3, 5, 5, 2, 9, 7, 3, 4, 6, 3, 4, 3, 4, 1
SK4, 2, 9, 5, 7, 0, 8, 6, 6, 7, 9, 0, 1, 3, 1, 6, 0, 0, 1, 3, 8, 5, 4, 0, 9, 7, 1, 4, 5, 2, 8
SK5, 2, 6, 8, 0, 3, 5, 5, 2, 5, 9, 4, 5, 3, 5, 7, 8, 8, 2, 5, 9, 3, 8, 6, 7, 8, 7, 4, 1, 2, 3
SK6, 2, 7, 5, 9, 1, 9, 8, 4, 1, 7, 3, 7, 0, 8, 4, 5, 9, 2, 4, 4, 8, 7, 9, 2, 2, 7, 9, 1, 6, 9
SK7, 6, 9, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 8, 3, 8, 7, 1, 9, 6, 1, 5, 3, 4, 7, 9, 5, 5, 9, 1, 4, 4, 0, 2, 0
SK8, 2, 8, 8, 3, 1, 1, 0, 8, 5, 9, 0, 3, 1, 6, 8, 7, 9, 6, 7, 7, 0, 9, 5, 2, 5, 0, 2, 1, 8, 6
SK9, 7, 1, 8, 8, 4, 4, 2, 2, 7, 4, 0, 6, 9, 5, 5, 4, 9, 1, 8, 6, 3, 4, 8, 2, 7, 9, 7, 2, 6, 6
```

Each lists last numbers will be found and compared, so SK1 would be -3, SK2 would be -3, SK4 would be 6. The only value returned should be the key value "SK*number*" and its value and the increase.

So if SK 4 was the highest the result would be "SK4 - 8, INCREASE 6"

Currently, I can search through and find the end int on each tail, below is my code, how would I modify for the changes I have stated above?

```
  val mapdata = readFile("data.txt")

  //5 - Show Current Stock Level (W)
  def handleFive(): Boolean = {
    mnuShowSingleDataStock(currentStockLevel)
    true
  }

// Returns a single result, not a list
  def mnuShowSingleDataStock(stock: (String) => (String,Int)) = {
    print("Stock > ")
    val data = stock(readLine)
    println(s"${data._1}: ${data._2}")
  }

  //Show last element in the list, most current
  def currentStockLevel (stock: String): (String, Int) = {
    (stock, mapdata.get (stock).map(findLast(_)).getOrElse(0))
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how your code is related to what you requested, but you can use `takeRight` to get last N elements from a list - in this case you can take the last two and perform a simple mapping over the map values to compute the "increase", then find the element with the maximal increase using `maxBy`:

```
val result: (String, (Int, Int)) = mapdata
  .mapValues(_.takeRight(2)) // take only last two ints from each list
  .mapValues { case List(i1, i2) => (i2, i2 - i1) } // compute "increase"
  .maxBy { case (s, (last, increase)) => increase } // maximum by increase value

// result is (Key, (last value, increase)) 

println(s"${result._1} - ${result._2._1}, INCREASE ${result._2._2}")
// SK4 - 8, INCREASE 6
```

Comment: Was supplying my own code to show I wasn't just asking you to do all the work, I have done some and just wasn't sure how to continue on to the next problem. This works though, cheers

Comment: That's good - I now realize only the last of the 3 methods is relevant (right?) - if that's so, you can remove the other two, but indeed it's good that you've added that last one.